# Does romex wire between studs in a garage have to be encased in conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

What is the current code about a new wire run between studs on an unfinished garage wall? I am installing a switch between a GFCI  and an outdoor UF run to control an outdoor pole light.

Answer (score 3):

NEC Article 334.10 (A)(1) Allows NM to be installed in both exposed and concealed locations except areas where trim, doors, window casings, etc. Or where they would be susceptible to abnormal damage. Just make sure it is installed and stapled in the center of the stud. If you have to drill into a plate or stud it should be in the center also. If not protect with a nail plate. I like nail plates. They are inexpensive and easy to install. I would rather over do them than under do them.

Good luck